# Proper H Tag Usage For SEO

Tags: html5, tags

What is the up to date correct usage of the H tags?

I was originally told that it was only one H1 tag per page.

Now I am being told that you can use more than one h1 tag as long as it is only one per sectioning root or content section and that it is better than the former way.

What is the correct usage!

Answer (score 1):

I heard the first, but not the second. This is advice. There are no rules regarding `H1` tags. Search engines cannot dictate how to use HTML. Use as many as you want however you want.

However, the advice to use just one `H1` tag is generally a good one and fits convention. It is strong SEO advice. In addition, the `H1` tag should strongly support the title which is also supported by a more verbose rendition as a `description` meta-tag. This is standard advice for a good reason. It works. As well, following convention will not trigger any red flags.

With so many header tags available, there are plenty of options as not to need more than one `H1` tag. With CSS, style is not an issue. I am not sure why someone would use more than one `H1` tag under normal circumstances. I am not saying there may not be a valid reason to, just that I cannot imagine one.